# Setting up a equal function in common lisp using only "eq"

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've given the assingment to write a function in common lisp to compare two lists to see if they are equal and I have been bared from using the "equal" predicate I can only use "eq" and I seem to come to a wall. I get this error with my code EVAL: variable SETF has no value
The following restarts are available:
and he code:

```
(defun check(L1 L2)
  (cond
   ((eq L nil) nil)
   (setq x (first L1))
   (setq y (first L2))
   (setf L1 (rest L1))
   (setf L2 (rest L2))
   (if (eq x y) (check L1 L2))))

(defun b(L1 L2)
  (cond
   ((eq L1 nil) nil)
   (setf x (first L1))
   (setf y (first L2))
   (setf L1 (rest L1))
   (setf L2 (rest L2))
   (if (and (list x) (list y)
           (check(x y))
            (if (eq x y) (b(L1 L2))))))
```

Comment: Would you indent your code? There is a button that lets insert four spaces before a block of code, which will be shown as preformatted block then.

Comment: also: x and y are nowhere defined, what are they? Check the syntax of COND and see your indented code - does it match the syntax? What is the purpose of the functions B and CHECK? What should B do? What does CHECK check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
(defun compare-lists (list1 list2)
  (if (and (not (null list1)) 
           (not (null list2)))
      (let ((a (car list1)) (b (car list2)))
        (cond ((and (listp a) (listp b))
               (and (compare-lists a b)
                    (compare-lists (cdr list1) (cdr list2))))
              (t 
               (and (eq a b)
                    (compare-lists (cdr list1) (cdr list2))))))
      (= (length list1) (length list2))))
```

Tests:

```
? (compare-lists '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
T
? (compare-lists '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
NIL
? (compare-lists '(1 2 3) '(1 2 (3)))
NIL
? (compare-lists '(1 2 (3)) '(1 2 (3)))
T
? (compare-lists '(1 2 (a b c r)) '(1 2 (a b c (r))))
NIL
? (compare-lists '(1 2 (a b c (r))) '(1 2 (a b c (r))))
T
```

Comment: (if a b nil) = (if a b) = (and a b)

Comment: (cond ((...) (t (if a b nil)))) = (cond ((...) (a b)))