# Common Lisp: How to check set equality, ignoring order?

Tags: lisp, set, common-lisp, equality

Similar to this question:

[Setting up a equal function in common lisp using only "eq"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427321/setting-up-a-equal-function-in-common-lisp-using-only-eq)

except, I'd like to be compare two sets for equality, disregarding order. How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930493/a-function-to-compare-sets-help-improving-efficiency

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of set functions in CL. Among those you can use `(null (set-exclusive-or set-a set-b))`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer that you are looking for, but if you want to deal with sets, I recommend using [Fset](http://common-lisp.net/project/fset/), a functional set-theoretic collections library for CL. The [tutorial](http://common-lisp.net/project/fset/Site/FSet-Tutorial.html) gives  a good idea of what it does.