# Pausing and Resuming Iteration over two Lists?

Tags: list, lisp, pattern-matching, common-lisp

I'm new to Common Lisp and have been working on a simple pattern matcher as a first project.  I'm having trouble using the star (*) operator to represent 0 or more of any element in a list.  So the pattern (x * z) and the matcher (x y y y z) would return true, but the pattern (x * z) and the matcher (x y) would return false.

My first thoughts:

```
(loop for x in pattern-list
  (eq x '*)
  ;if x is *, pause iterating through this list
  (loop for y in matcher-list
        ;somehow iterate one more value in the pattern list
        (eq x y) ;does the value just after the * in the pattern list equal the value in y?
        ;if they aren't the same symbol, just iterate matcher until they match, then resume incrementing though the pattern list
))
```

Sorry if my syntax and parenthesis are a little off.

This is a smaller piece to a larger pattern matcher that I was working on.  Here's what I have so far (In this case, list1 is pattern-list and list2 is matcher-list):

The bulk of this code originated from this SO post:

[Setting up a equal function in common lisp using only "eq"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427321/setting-up-a-equal-function-in-common-lisp-using-only-eq)

```
(defun comp-q (list1 list2) ;defun
  (if (and (not (null list1)) ;if list1 is not null AND
       (not (null list2))) ;if list2 is not null
  (let ((a (car list1)) (b (car list2))) ;a is the car (front) of list1 and b is the car of list 2
    (cond ((and (listp a) (listp b)) ;cond, evaluate the first thing in the list - are a and b lists?
           (and (comp-q a b) ;recursive call on a and b
                (comp-q (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))) ;recursive call on the cdr (tail) of a and b
          (t ;like an else for cond
           (and (or (eq a b) (eq a '?)) ;are a and b equal OR is a a '?'
                (comp-q (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))) ;recursive call on the cdr of a and b
  (= (length list1) (length list2)))) ;are the lists equal?  only triggered if the null test fails (are they both not null)
```

Is using the `loop` macro my best bet?  Is it possible to "pause" or keep track of iterations over a list (I know this is array-esque)?  Or should I try to continue working recursively by calling the `car` and `cdr` of each list that is being implemented in the comp-q `defun`?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have the `loop`s nested. Otherwise, for each `x` in `pattern-list`, you would be iterating over the whole `matcher-list`. I recommend taking a recursive approach, at least for the start - it should be more intuitive than using `loop`. Start by defining the base case: Given the lists, does the first element of `matcher-list` match the pattern? If not, fail; if yes, accept the first element and recursively call with tails of the lists as appropriate.

Comment: There are different matching strategies to begin with. So to answer you whether `loop` is any good for it, you'd have to tell what are the rules you use to match stuff. Think of CFG vs PEG rules. How do you solve priority and choice issues. Are you necessarily matching the longest possible extension, or the shortest and so on. I'd also be looking into `iterate` library, because it allows extending iteration macros in a portable way. Also, there are already a bunch of CL pattern-matching libraries, `optima` is a good one in my experience.

Comment: I've remembered about `iterate` because it has generators, something that would allow you to advance the iterator driving the loop, which looks like the particular problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has given any answer yet, and since a recursive approach was suggested, I have come up with an example in Racket to get you started. It should be straightforward to convert to Common Lisp.

```
(define (match pattern matcher)

  ; is the symbol a wildcard (i.e. does it end with an asterisk?
  ;   yes -> return true + the symbol without the asterisk
  ;   no  -> return false + the symbol itself
  (define (is-wildcard sym)
    (let ((str (symbol->string sym)))
      (if (string=? (substring str (sub1 (string-length str))) "*")
          (values #t (string->symbol (substring str 0 (sub1 (string-length str)))))
          (values #f sym))))

  ; we know wi is a wildcard; let's loop over matcher until done
  (define (match-wildcard wi pattern matcher)
    (if (empty? matcher)
        (list (cdr pattern) matcher)
        (if (eq? wi (car matcher))
            (match-wildcard wi pattern (cdr matcher))
            (list (cdr pattern) matcher))))

  ; main loop
  (if (or (empty? pattern) (empty? matcher))
      (and (empty? pattern )(empty? matcher))
      (let ((pa (car pattern)) (ma (car matcher)))
        (if (eq? pa ma)
            (match (cdr pattern) (cdr matcher))
            (let-values (((wildcard wi) (is-wildcard pa)))
              (if wildcard
                  (apply match (match-wildcard wi pattern matcher))
                  #f))))))
```

Examples:

```
(match '(x y* z) '(x y y y z))
=> #t

(match '(x z* y) '(x y))
=> #t

(match '(x y* z) '(x y))
=> #f

(match '(x y*) '(x y))
=> #t
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you very much!  I ended up doing something very similar in Common Lisp, but it's always great to have multiple insights.  `((eq a '*) ;is a a '*'
              (or 
               (comp-q2 (cdr list1) list2 c) ;increment list1 but not list2
               (comp-q2 list1 (cdr list2) c))) ;increment list2 but not list1`